# Is it anyway to distribute package to different Nexus remote repository while running mvn deploy?

Tags: maven, nexus

In this case, there are two different Nexus remote repositories. The package should be pushed to both of the repositories while running mvn deploy.
I try to add them under the "distributionManagement" label in the pom.xml as following

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>rdc-releases-0</id>
        <url>https://test-0.com/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>rdc-releases-1</id>
        <url>https://test-1.com/release</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

but there is an error shown with the second "repository" label. It seems that there should be only one repository label.

Is it anyway to distribute package to different Nexus remote repository while running mvn deploy? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Have you checked your settings.xml file to see whether you have the right permissions configured there matching both repositories? [Maven deployment](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-deployment-security-settings.html)

Comment: the settings.xml seems right.
while running mvn deploy, the error message is given as following:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM /Users/shike/IdeaProjects/leopard-gitnurse-new/gitnurse/pom.xml: Duplicated tag: 'repository'

Comment: Yeap, I double checked the [Maven pom file specification](https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd)  and it seems that the distributionManagement section does not support multiple different repositories for releases. You can have a snapshotRepository and a repository there though. So J. Fabian answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

But it is rarely necessary. Usually, you deploy just to one repository. The other repository then defines a proxy on the first, so that it is also able to download the artifacts.

Comment: Hi Meier, thank you for your reply!
I met a problem while creating a proxy repository in the second Nexus which point to the first remote repository. when a snapshot is pushed to the first repository, the proxy repository could not get the latest snapshot.

Comment: This is probably related to how often the repository updates. There is probably some setting for this.

Comment: Yes, there is a setting "Maximum metadata age" of proxy repository in Nexus. When the value set to 0, the latest snapshot in first repository will be used. Thanks for your hint!